# Existence of Fredholm operators of a given index in a non-separable Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. The (Fredholm) index of a bounded operator $T : H \to H$ is defined as $$ \mathrm{index}(T) = \dim \ker(T) - \dim \mathrm{coker}(T), $$ whenever the kernel and cokernel of $T$ are finite-dimensional. Operators satisfying these conditions are called Fredholm operators. When $H$ is separable (equivalently, has a countably infinite orthonormal basis), $F_n(H) \neq \emptyset$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$, which can be seen by picking a countable orthonormal basis and calculating the index of left and right shift operators with respect to this basis.

If $H$ is non-separable, is it possible that for some $n \in \mathbb Z$, the set $F_n(H)$ of Fredholm operators of index $n$ is empty?

**Edit:** I was able to simplify the problem with a little algebra. Any bounded invertible operator is a Fredholm operator, so $F_0(H) \neq \emptyset$. If there is a Fredholm operator $T$ of index $1$, then, given an integer $n \neq 0$, we can (much like the separable case with the shift) apply powers of $T$ and its adjoint to find an operator of index $n$. Specifically,

1. If $n > 0$, then $$ \mathrm{index}(T^n) =  \mathrm{index}(T \circ \cdots \circ T) = n \cdot \mathrm{index}(T) = n.$$
2. If $n < 0$, then $$ \mathrm{index}(T^{*(-n)}) = -n \cdot \mathrm{index}(T^*) = -n \cdot (-1) = n. $$

So my question will be rephrased as follows: *If $H$ is non-separable, is it possible that $F_1(H) \neq \emptyset$?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $H$ is infinite dimensional then it may be written as $H_0\oplus H_1$, with $H_0$ separable infinite dimensional,
and for any Fredholm operator $T$ on $H_0$ one has that
$T\oplus I$ is Fredholm on $H$ and
$\text{ind}(T\oplus I)=  \text{ind}(T)$.

Picking a Fredholm operator $T$ on $H_0$ with a given index $n$, one then gets a Fredholm operator $T\oplus I$ on $H$ with the same index.

Comment: Could we say that this sum of operators is bounded?

Comment: The direct sum of bounded operators is bounded, with norm equal to the maximum of the norms of the operators involved.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Doesn't your claim require that $H_0 \oplus H_1$ be topologically isomorphic to $H$? If true how can I check this?

Comment: My claim actually requires a lot more than that:  it requires that the norm on $H_0\oplus H_1$ be defined as
  $$
  \|(\xi _0,\xi _1)\| =
  (\|\xi _0\|^2  +   \|\xi _1\|^2)^{1/2},
  $$
  which makes $H_0\oplus H_1$ isometrically isomorphic to $H$, assuming, of course, that $H_1$ is the orthogonal complement of
$H_0$ within $H$.  Incidentally this is the standard norm one puts on the direct sum of two Hilbert spaces.

Comment: I see! But in your definition $H_0$ is a separable subspace of $H$. Why is $H_0$ also the orthogonal complement of $H_1$?

Comment: Choose $H_0$ to be any separable subspace and set $H_1=H_0^\perp$.